# Save a JsObject to JSON file (java.lang.String cannot be cast to scala.scalajs.js.Any)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, playframework

I am using play framework to create a json object, after that, I should save these objects in a json file. 
linksEvolution is a sequence of JsObject objects.

```
  var linksEvolution: Seq[JsObject] = Seq()
```

a JsObject is created by :

```
    val user = Json.obj(
        "link" -> [87, 98],
        "reference" -> [1,8],
    )
```

updating the list of JsObject:

```
    val tmplinksEvolution = linksEvolution :+ user

    linksEvolution = tmplinksEvolution
```

When the update of linksEvolution is done, now I create an RDD by linksEvolution, so each element of the RDD will be saved on a file, like :

```
     //create the RDD
     val rddLinksEvolution = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(linksEvolution)
     //convert each JsObject to string
     val tmprddLinksEvolution = rddLinksEvolution.map(_.toString())
     //save the data on a text file
     tmprddLinksEvolution.saveAsTextFile("testSavingFile_2.json")
```

The problem:
I got as error :

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to scala.scalajs.js.Any
```

This exception is raised only when I use the jar file given by maven install. But, when the same code work fine when I run it by using the Scala IDE (run scala application)!

Edit : example in a main function and the dependencies

**Full example:**

```
import play.api.libs.json.{ JsArray, JsNumber, JsObject, Json }
  import org.apache.spark.{ SparkConf, SparkContext }

  object TestJson {

  def main(args: Array[String]) = {

   var linksEvolution: Seq[JsObject] = Seq()
   val user = Json.obj(
  "link" -> JsArray(Seq(JsNumber(87), JsNumber(98))),
  "reference" -> JsArray(Seq(JsNumber(1), JsNumber(8))))


val tmplinksEvolution = linksEvolution :+ user
linksEvolution = tmplinksEvolution

val sc = new SparkContext(new    SparkConf().setAppName("test").setMaster("local"))

//create the RDD
val rddLinksEvolution = sc.parallelize(linksEvolution)
//convert each JsObject to string
val tmprddLinksEvolution = rddLinksEvolution.map(_.toString())
//save the data on a text file
 tmprddLinksEvolution.saveAsTextFile("testSavingFile_kk2.json")
 }
}
```

**With dependencies :**

```
<dependencies>
  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.typesafe.play/play-json -->
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.typesafe.play</groupId>
    <artifactId>play-json_sjs0.6_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.0</version>
  </dependency>

  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-sql -->
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.0</version>
  </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried the example you mentioned and it works fine with me.

the only difference is defining the user object:

```
  val user = Json.obj(
    "link" -> JsArray(Seq(JsNumber(87), JsNumber(98))),
    "reference" -> JsArray(Seq(JsNumber(1), JsNumber(8)))
  )
```

Also you should notice that the output will be a directory not a text file. so you will find a directory with name "testSavingFile_2.json" and you will find multiple  files under this directory with names "part-00000", "part-00001", ...

Also, I'm not sure what imports do you use, but these are the imports I used:

```
import play.api.libs.json.{ JsArray, JsNumber, JsObject, Json }
```

Comment: that create a jsobject, but I can't use it for saving in file or print it. For example, I try to print user with :   println(user), I got :                                                                                      Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to scala.scalajs.js.Any
 at scala.scalajs.js.Any$.fromString(Any.scala:76)
 at play.api.libs.json.StaticBinding$.play$api$libs$json$StaticBinding$$fromString(StaticBinding.scala:101)

So the problem is at using the created object, specially when writing or printing !

Comment: Could you show me your full code with the imports and dependencies?

Comment: Here is the full working code I'm using: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/p8lcgqWaQZ2BYii5WH8tZA

Comment: and the depdendency I'm using is 
`"com.typesafe.play" %% "play-json" % "2.6.0"`

Comment: I am not familiar with sbt, I edited the post with your example and the dependencies, but I had the same problem.

Answer (score -1):

Finally the solution is found [here](https://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-to-create-json-strings-from-scala-objects) (Lift-JSON solution).

```
import scala.collection.mutable._
import net.liftweb.json._
import net.liftweb.json.Serialization.write

case class Person(name: String, address: Address)
case class Address(city: String, state: String)

object LiftJsonTest extends App {
    val p = Person("Alvin Alexander", Address("Talkeetna", "AK"))
    // create a JSON string from the Person, then print it
    implicit val formats = DefaultFormats
    val jsonString = write(p)
    println(jsonString)
}
```

By having a String, I created a RDD of these strings. After that, I saved the strings by using saveAsTextFile().